# Как найти слова окружающие нужное в строке php?

Tags: php

Как осуществить поиск в строке слова, а затем выдернуть слова, которые его окружают?
Например, из предложения сверху я нахожу слово "поиск", а затем мне надо записать слова "осуществить" и "в".. Я предполагаю, что можно разбить строку на слова в массив, а затем найти нужное в массиве и взять следующий и предыдущий, но это, как мне кажется, не рационально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это имели ввиду?

```
<?php
$sentence = 'Как осуществить поиск в строке слова, а затем выдернуть слова, которые его окружают?'; 
$arr=preg_split('/\s+поиск\s+/',$sentence);
$before=explode(' ',$arr[0]);
$after=explode(' ',$arr[1]);
print_r($before);
print_r($after);
```

http://ideone.com/KIYQES

(ограничения - разделитель единичный пробел, не хотел второй раз preg_split делать)

Answer (score 1):

И чем же это не рационально?

```
$sentence = 'Как осуществить поиск в строке слова, а затем выдернуть слова, которые его окружают?'; 
$words = preg_split('/\W+/u', $sentence); 
$idx = array_search('поиск', $words, true);
if($idx !== FALSE)
{
 /* нашли, берём соседей */
}
```